# Better way of using spring boot starters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I found two way of adding dependencies for spring boot rest service application.

Method 1 :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Method 2:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Both method given above does the same job? Any difference in performance?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The difference between these methods is that `spring-boot-starter-web` contains more dependencies than just `spring-boot-starter` and `spring-web`.

For the version 1.5.8.RELEASE it will be:

- spring-boot-starter
- spring-boot-starter-tomcat
- hibernate-validator
- jackson-databind
- spring-web
- spring-webmvc

All other stuff depends on your requirements. For instance, if you're developing commercial product you must check all included transitive dependencies for their licenses.

The general advice is to use only features you need. Don't forget that you still can depend on top level artifact excluding not required parts using Maven feature.

At for the performance boost, basically it should not be that much. The difference is only if the Spring (with top-level artifact dependency) will load and auto configure some features which are not practically used in your code (during the classpath scanning). The startup time could be slightly increased by the same reason.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously second approach is better i.e. using springboot starter pom.

Reasons I say that for are as follows:-

1. It allows `zero configuration` or `auto configuration` i.e. most of the web related settings would be given to you by default. e.g. by default tomcat server would be integrated, springboot dependencies would be added for you, automatic registration of converter and other web related dependencies etc. See [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-auto-configuration) link.
2. You could take advantage of easy override i.e. if tomorrow you want to use jetty in place of tomcat just add the jetty dependency and it's configurations and now you could use jetty.
3. Your `pom.xml` would be neater and more readable as less no. of dependencies are put inside it and picked from starter poms.
4. Easy compatibility management. By default spring-boot picks up the version of `starter parent`. Hence, you could rest assured that all compatible dependencies would be downloaded as part of mvn dependencies and if you specifically want to upgrade any of those you could. But this gives advantage of upgrading to compatible dependencies by just changing the version of springboot starter parent(Note: You could use dependency management as well in place of starter parent pom. See [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent) link).

Performance wise there would be a trade-off as springboot by default downloads  more dependencies than minimum required initially. But over the time as application starts becoming mature most of these dependencies are used anyways.

Comment: But by seeing at other answers, they say my app will have unnecessary jar files which can make my app fat.

Comment: Yes! I agree, but overall the default dependencies that are added by default are a choice of spring community. Springboot takes the opinionated view of spring community to decide the auto configuration and by default added such dependencies only. Hence, I said performance wise there is a tradeoff but that's really negligible as these are the dependencies used by a large group of spring users by default.

Comment: 1) Autoconfiguration should work with 1 approach since he got `spring-boot-starter`
2) Indeed, you don't need default Tomcat included if you want Jetty server, so use only the features you need
3) Come on, modern IDE will take care about it
4) Well, he still can inherit his `pom.xml` from Spring bom, or import it, depending on current settings.
So I basically don't agree with your post but will not downvote it

Comment: @SergeyProkofiev 1.  but will the starter provide the tomcat, hibernate and jacksonn-databind? 2. I said it will override when you add jetty and tomcat won't be downloaded. 3. Disagree! IDE could take care of it only upto a level when the pom grows larger it becomes a tedious task. 4. I meant to say that you are on safer side as by default the version is chosen by springboot untill you explicitly mention it. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: @VinayPrajapati do they required if he mentioned that the application worked fine with both configurations? Don't think so.

Comment: I agree with Sergey. And I think for maintainability of POM, I do not mind if it is big. At least I will know what all dependencies are added and hence will be more comfortable. But looks like it is debatable and depends on each individuals. Anyways thanks guys.

Comment: @SergeyProkofiev yup! I agree with your point. Though my answer revolves around the opinionated benefits of using web starter pom.

Comment: @Pradeep Yes! It's rather than being debatable, it's more opinionated. Springboot is a by product of the factory of problems came due to large pom files.

Comment: @Vinay Oh Yeah. That's true.